# Determine $(f+g)(x)$ and state restrictions on the domain.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am asked to determine $(f+g)(x)$ and state any restrictions on the domain.

\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
f(x) & = \sqrt{x-1} \\
g(x) & = -x
\end{split}
\end{equation}

I have the first part, but I am having trouble determining the restrictions on the domain.
\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
(f+g)(x) & = \sqrt{x-1}+(-x) \\
 & = \sqrt{x-1}-x
\end{split}
\end{equation}
My questions are: How could I go about finding the domain for a function like this? Is it as simple as saying as long as the square root is not negative $x\geq0$, $x\in R$ with no other restrictions?

Would the correct

Comment: are there any restrictions for the range? If it's real then the [current] answers would be right but not if $f$ or $g$ can take complex values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if you know the domain of a function $f(x)$ and a function $g(x)$, then the domain of the function $(f + g)(x)$ is $$ \text{(domain of } f(x)) \cap \text{(domain of } g(x)). $$

Here, $f(x) = \sqrt{x - 1}$, and we cannot have any negative numbers under the square root, so we know $x - 1 \geq 0$, which gives $x \geq 1$.  In interval notation, this is $[1, \infty)$.

$g(x) = -x$, and we can plug any real number into this, so it is defined everywhere.  So the domain of $g(x)$ is $\mathbb{R}$ (all real numbers).  You can also write it as $(-\infty, \infty)$.

So the domain of $(f + g)(x)$ is, as we said, the domain of $f(x)$ intersected with the domain of $g(x)$.  This is $[1, \infty) \cap (-\infty, \infty)$.  If you know how intersections work, then you will know $[1, \infty) \cap (-\infty, \infty) = [1, \infty)$.

Thus, our final answer for the domain of $(f + g)(x)$ is $[1, \infty)$.

Comment: By the way, you go through the exact same process to find the domains of $(f - g)(x)$ and $(fg)(x)$.  

The only time the process is different is for $(f/g)(x)$.  In that case, you still find $(\text{domain of } f) \cap (\text{domain of } g)$, but after you find this intersection, you must remove any values that make the function $g(x)$ equal to 0, because $g(x)$ is in the denominator, and we cannot have 0 in the denominator.

Comment: Helpful response, Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can think of it as:

$$(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$$

So your domain will be the domain when both $f$ and $g$ are defined simultaneously. In this case you have no problems with $g(x)$ so your domain will be those points where the argument of the root is non negative:

$$x-1 \geq 0 $$

Answer (score 0):

$x\geq1$. This is to make sure that the value under the root is non-negative.